# Как правильно: джинсов или джинс?

Tags: морфология

У слова "джинсы" нет единственного числа, и я не знаю, по какому правилу тут образуется родительный падеж. И как будет: "джинсов" (вроде, на язык лучше ложится) или "джинс"?

Answer (score 1):

Склоняется по той же модели, что и "трусы", только ударение на первом слоге.